# Zend CLI Tool include error

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework2, zend-tool

I'm trying to install Zend_Tools.
I tried the solutions in other questions but anything worked.
I'm using Windows7 with XAMPP therefore my php lies in C:\xampp\php.
I included php into PATH, added my ZendFramework\library to include_path.
I have some other php installations on my system but I think I included it right. php -i | more gives:

```
Loaded Configuration File => C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

and

```
Zend Extension => 220090626
Zend Extension Build => API220090626,TS,VC9
```

Now, when I try to run zf.bat. I get the error:

```
ZF Error:In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path...
```

I also added an echo of get_include_path() i the top of zf.php it also gives me the right path:

```
.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\Users\Felix_2\Documents\programmierung\ZendFramework\libr
ary;C:\Users\Felix_2\Documents\programmierung\ZendFramework\library
```

In the ZendFramework\library folders is one folder "Zend" with Zend's packages as subfolders, thats the right folder, isn't it?br/>
Don't know how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that `Zend` folder to your path. So it should be `......ZendFramework/library/Zend` that should fix it.

Comment: I've tried this and all combinations of slashs and backslashes directly in the zf.php, nothing worked.

Comment: Try editing your php.ini file then, there should be an `include_path` option in that.

Comment: I forgot: I'm using Zend Framework 2beta.Could this be the problem, the zf.php,zf.bat weren't included I downloaded them seperately